# Add minimum value as a new column using mutate

Tags: r, tidyr, dplyr

I have the following dataframe in R

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)### IMPORTED LIBRARIES
DF<-data.frame("Index"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
DF$CI=c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", 'A1', "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A9")
```

The dataframe consists of two columns, an Index column with serial numbers from one to 10 and a second column CI. the values in CI columns may be unique or duplicated. The dataframe appears as follows

```
   Index CI
1      1 A1
2      2 A2
3      3 A3
4      4 A4
5      5 A1
6      6 A6
7      7 A7
8      8 A8
9      9 A9
10    10 A9
```

I would like to add a column EI that indicates the correct Index value in case a value in CI is duplicated. The expected output is as follows

```
    Index CI EI
 1      1 A1  1
 2      2 A2  2
 3      3 A3  3
 4      4 A4  4
 5      5 A1  1
 6      6 A6  6
 7      7 A7  7
 8      8 A8  8
 9      9 A9  9
 10    10 A9  9
```

The column EI should show the corresponding index value that corresponds to the entry in CI column. In case of a duplication, the value returned should be the minimal index value. I have tried the following code using DPLYR

```
  DF%>%mutate(EI=case_when(CI==unique(CI)~min(Index)))
```

I am getting the following output.

```
    Index CI EI
 1      1 A1  1
 2      2 A2  1
 3      3 A3  1
 4      4 A4  1
 5      5 A1 NA
 6      6 A6 NA
 7      7 A7 NA
 8      8 A8 NA
 9      9 A9 NA
 10    10 A9 NA
```

I have tried this code as well but am not getting the desired output

```
    DF%>%mutate(EI=min(Index))
```

Output

```
      Index CI EI
   1      1 A1  1
   2      2 A2  1
   3      3 A3  1
   4      4 A4  1
   5      5 A1  1
   6      6 A6  1
   7      7 A7  1
   8      8 A8  1
   9      9 A9  1
   10    10 A9  1
```

I request a little help here. Am using DPLYR as the dataset is large( i have given a toy dataset) and a loop is taking very long.

Comment: `DF %>%
  mutate(EI = group_indices(., CI))` Or Perhaps you are looking for `DF %>%
  group_by(CI) %>%
  mutate(EI = min(Index))
`

Comment: alternative: `DF %>% mutate(EI = match(CI, CI))`

Comment: @RonakShah Also `EI = first(Index)`, instead of `min(Index)`.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas how does first (Index) differ from min(Index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the minimum value of `Index`, within matching values of `CI`. That's what `group_by()` is for:

```
DF %>%
    group_by(CI) %>%
    mutate(EI = min(Index))
```

Comment: Alright. That explains it. Once grouped, the CI==CI is redundant. Thank